# Python - How to add n zeros randomly in an existing matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

i have this array that i generated using the default_rng:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(seed=10)
rng = rng.integers(1,20,(5,10))
rng

>>>array([[15, 19,  6,  4, 16, 16, 10,  3, 16, 10],
          [ 3,  3,  8, 14,  8, 16,  1,  9, 10, 19],
          [ 5, 16,  2,  7, 15, 11, 18, 15, 18, 16],
          [ 3, 18, 17,  3, 19, 15,  6,  3,  8, 18],
          [15,  5, 10, 17, 13,  6,  3, 19,  5, 10]], dtype=int64)
```

I want to add 10 zeros in this matrix using the generator with seed=5.
I thought to create a new array with dimessions [5,10] and to put 10 zeros inside and the rest to be one and then mutliply the two arrays but i have to use the generator so i can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `np.random.choice` to choose the index, then set the values at those indexes to `0`:

```
np.random.seed(10)
idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(5*10), size=5, replace=False)

rng.ravel()[idx] = 0
```

Output:

```
array([[15, 19,  6,  4, 16, 16, 10,  3, 16, 10],
       [ 3,  3,  8, 14,  8, 16,  1,  9, 10, 19],
       [ 5, 16,  2,  0, 15, 11, 18, 15, 18, 16],
       [ 3, 18, 17,  3, 19, 15,  6,  0,  8, 18],
       [15,  5,  0, 17,  0,  6,  3,  0,  5, 10]])
```

Comment: Yeah i tried it, but choice might take two or more same numbers e.g two 10 and when i try to implement the idx == 0 i take back 9 zeros instead 10.

Comment: @LefterisKyprianou notice the `replace=False` option. It's `True` by default.

Comment: The same result even replace is true or False

Comment: If that's the case, it's definitely a bug. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: `idx = np.random.choice(rng.ravel(), 10, replace= False)
print(idx)
rng.ravel()[idx] = 0
rng `

Comment: So instead of take 10 zeros i take only 6 becaus of 15 appears five times in my idx.

`[10 17  3  6 15 15 15 16 15 15]

array([[15, 19,  6,  0, 16, 16,  0,  3, 16, 10],
       [ 0,  3,  8, 14,  8,  0,  0,  0, 10, 19],
       [ 5, 16,  2,  7, 15, 11, 18, 15, 18, 16],
       [ 3, 18, 17,  3, 19, 15,  6,  3,  8, 18],
       [15,  5, 10, 17, 13,  6,  3, 19,  5, 10]], dtype=int64)`

Comment: I put the same code underneath with legible syntax

Answer (score 0):

Of course

```
idx = np.random.choice(rng.ravel(), 10, replace= False)
print(idx)
rng.ravel()[idx] = 0
rng
```

Output

```
       [10 17  3  6 15 15 15 16 15 15]

array([[15, 19,  6,  0, 16, 16,  0,  3, 16, 10],
       [ 0,  3,  8, 14,  8,  0,  0,  0, 10, 19],
       [ 5, 16,  2,  7, 15, 11, 18, 15, 18, 16],
       [ 3, 18, 17,  3, 19, 15,  6,  3,  8, 18],
       [15,  5, 10, 17, 13,  6,  3, 19,  5, 10]], dtype=int64)
```

So instead of take 10 zeros i take only 6 becaus of 15 appears five times in my idx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng(seed=10)
a=rng.integers(1,20,(5,10)) #creates the initial matrix
print("This is the initial matrix")
print(a)

rep= default_rng(seed=5)
row=rep.integers(0,5,(10,)) 
print("This is the random row index")
print(row)

column=rep.integers(0,10,(10,))
print("This is the random column index")
print(column)
a[row,column]=0 #set the random seats to 0
```

You get 5 random places in the matrix to replace with the value zero (0)